# How to play AVI videos on website?

Tags: javascript, html, video, web

I'm creating a web system wherein the user can view the videos of AVI format. Is there any way to do this without making use of codecs? I want this to be hassle free for the users that even if the user uses a Mac or a windows or Linux-based computer, he/she can still view the videos.

the videos are saved on my web server and I just have to access their URL as the source of the video. These videos are in AVI format since these videos are taken from the Pepper, the robot by Aldebaran.

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: AVI file format is a MS propriety file type. AVI files do not stream over the net therefore the person needs to download the full movie before it starts to play. Most browser support the mp4 format. This site http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/ demonstrates the new html5 video element.

Comment: "Is there any way to do this without making use of codecs?" — No. The video has to be encoded *somehow*. Avi is just the container. Inside it is video (encoded using a video codec) and audio (encoded using an audio codec). You're asking for English without letters. The probably is using codecs (and container formats) that are *supported* by the clients.